# Tinymce paste image?

Tags: image, tinymce, paste

I have searched the net a lot and i didnt find solution for this issuse? Is there anyway to paste formated word document in tinymce but with picture inside?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way that i know of to do this becasue of the structure of the word document.
In Word images are not inserted using a href with an image location. In word images are usually referencing to local files. To display an image in an editor/web page you need the image location or a base64-encoded string (pasting from word does not deliver this information).

Answer (score 0):

Useful, but old, link http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5585

Some php code that convert inline IMG tags with data:url to actual image files on the server side using PHP : http://jk3.us/2011/10/31/pasting-images-in-tinymce/